# Is mutual information convex in the joint distribution?

Tags: convex-analysis, information-theory, entropy

Assume some joint distribution $P(X,Y) = P(Y|X)P(X)$.

It is well know that, for fixed $P(Y|X)$, mutual information is a concave function of $P(X)$ and, for fixed $P(X)$, a convex function of $P(Y|X)$ (e.g. see Theorem 2.7.4 in Cover & Thomas).

Is the mutual information function convex in the joint distribution $P(X,Y)$, given the marginals are *not* fixed?  I have read conflicting statements.  For example,

- M Mihm, K Ozbek, "Decision Making with Rational Inattention" [(pdf)](http://econ.as.nyu.edu/docs/IO/27273/Mihm_10252012.pdf)  says it is convex (see statement right after eq.3)
- AG Stefani et al, "A Tight Lower Bound on the Mutual Information of a Binary and an Arbitrary Finite Random Variable in Dependence of the Variational Distance" [(pdf)](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.5937v2.pdf) says it is not convex (first paragraph).

I suspect it is neither concave nor convex but am looking for a definitive statement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is neither convex nor concave. You can work it out using Bernoulli random variables.

*Not convex*:

1) Let $X$ and $Y$ be i.i.d. Bernoulli with $Pr[X=1]=1/2$.  Then $I(X,Y)=0$.

2) Let $A=B=1$ (constants). Then $I(A,B)=0$.

3) Let $(W,Z) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
(X,Y) & \mbox{with prob 1/2} \\
(A,B) & \mbox{with prob 1/2} 
\end{array}\right.
$

The joint probability distribution for $(W,Z)$ is a convex combination of those for $(X,Y)$ and $(A,B)$.  Yet, $I(W,Z)>0$.

*Not concave*:

1) Let $X$ and $Y$ be i.i.d. Bernoulli with $Pr[X=1]=1/2$. Then $I(X,Y)=0$.

2) Let $A=B$ where $A$ is Bernoulli with $Pr[A=1]=1/2$.  Then $I(A,B)=1$.

3) Let $(W,Z) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
(X,Y) & \mbox{with prob 1/2} \\
(A,B) & \mbox{with prob 1/2} 
\end{array}\right.
$

Then $Pr[W=1]=Pr[Z=1]=1/2$ and: 
\begin{align}
Pr[(W,Z)=(0,0)] &= 3/8\\
Pr[(W,Z)=(0,1)] &= 1/8\\
Pr[(W,Z)=(1,0)] &= 1/8\\
Pr[(W,Z)=(1,1)] &= 3/8
\end{align} 
and you can show that $I(W,Z) < 1/2 = (1/2)I(X,Y)+(1/2)I(A,B)$.

Comment: I now see how MI being concave in $P(X)$ and convex $P(Y|X)$ obviously suggests how it can't be convex or concave in $P(X,Y)$.  However, these examples are great -- thanks!